# Not Secure error in Stack Overflow for Teams Help Center page

Tags: bug, status-completed, ssl, stack-overflow-for-teams

In the [Stack Overflow Teams -> Following and watching tags](https://www.stackoverflow.help/support/solutions/articles/36000042022-following-and-watching-tags) page, due to few `http://` images the page received the *Connection is Not Secure* error.

The http:// images are:

> https://i.stack.imgur.com/s3aR0.png
>   https://i.stack.imgur.com/S4vNW.png
>   https://i.stack.imgur.com/fT9a7.png

The `http://` images in the page, can be update with `https://` ?

Comment: @Samuel They're actually two different issues (both fixed now). The other one was because FreshDesk's certificate hadn't been updated to include our domain yet. This one was because of insecure images.

Comment: @animuson sorry, I jumped the gun there